# Can Go compiler be installed on Windows?

Tags: windows, go

I've been looking on [golang.org](http://golang.org/) for a Windows compiler, but I can't seem to find it. I can only see Linux and OS X compilers. Does anyone know if Go programming can be done on Windows, or is it something that Google hasn't implemented yet?

Update: appears that as of now (Nov. 2012) [golang.org](http://golang.org/) has official binary releases for windows 32/x86_64.

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts - you'll find your answer there.

Comment: http://gofmt.com/compile.html if you want to try some non-destructive Go programming on Windows. It can compile, link, and run your programs and show you the output.

Please send me a private message if you find any vulnerability on that site. Thanks!

Comment: Update: erGo compiler was released for beta testing this week. The developer Russel Newquist answered in the comments below. http://www.newquistsolutions.com/ergo

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the [golang.org](https://golang.org/) website offers official windows packages since the first official (1.0) release.

Answer (score 54):

There are now installers for Windows, see [Go under Windows](http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/WindowsSupport)

**HelloWorld.go**

```
package main

func main() {
    println("Hello World!");
}
```

Compile with `8g`, link with `8l` and then execute. Example:

```
8g HelloWorld.go
8l -o HelloWorld.exe HelloWorld.8
HelloWorld
```

Comment: Another Win32 build of Go (released 2010-08-04): http://code.google.com/p/gomingw/downloads/list

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot get this port to work correctly. the 8l linker always complains about runtime.a missing and it also crashes shortly after invocation.

Comment: @Victor: I've just set this up (on 2010-12-11), and it works fine for compiling and linking the HelloWorld, PrimeSieve and Wiki examples.  And all three programs run.

Comment: The mingw port seems to work with no need for installation of any special environment (http://code.google.com/p/gomingw/downloads/list). At least it compiles and links several examples I have tried.

Comment: thanks, I've posted about this issue and I found a resolution for it already. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383377/go-windows-port-build-problems-8l-linker-crashes/4384836#4384836

Comment: This new release worked great for me on Windows (from the 3rd of May). Easy installer.
http://code.google.com/p/gomingw/downloads/list

Comment: If I remember good, you can't run goinstall with it. (now in linux ;P)

Comment: Oh, okay. I've only tried goinstall on Arch Linux, so I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 23):

It hasn't made it onto the Go Lang FAQ yet, but from [the changelog](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-checkins/browse_thread/thread/fdea6d681b9f692d):

> Why doesn't Go run on Windows?
>   We understand that a significant fraction of computers in the world 
>   run Windows and it would be great if those computers could run Go 
>   programs. However, the Go team is small and we don't have the 
>   resources to do a Windows port at the moment.  We would be 
>   more than willing to answer questions and offer advice to anyone 
>   willing to develop a Windows version.

Comment: Although this answer is heavily upvoted, it is now out of date.

Answer (score 12):

**Yes!** As of 2012 the Go homepage offers an official Windows installer (32 or 64 bit) https://golang.org/dl/

Answer (score 7):

Despite the fact that Go is only two days old, this question has *already* become a FAQ on the Go mailinglist. (Unfortunately, it has not yet been added to the FAQ list on the website.)

Basically, Go is done by a very small group of people, so they simply do not have the time nor the resources to do a Windows port. That very small group of people also happens to be the people who invented Unix, so that was kind of a natural first target.

Comment: AFAIK, they develop Go during their 20% time, not full time. (That's what I read, anyway.) Anyway, my answer was meant to be very-large-tongue-very-deep-in-cheek.

Comment: Actually, the history page states that while it started out as a spare-time project, it is now a full-time project for at least some of the developers. I edited the answer to basically remove the remarks about part-time constraints.

Comment: And I'm upvoting you for that :)

Comment: They invented Unix? So this is a retirement project?

Comment: Well, they also invented Plan9, the successor to Unix. And Inferno, the successor to Plan9. And C. And Limbo, the garbage collected systems programming language that Inferno is written in. (So, in some sense the successor to C and predecessor to Go.) And the Newsqueak concurrent programming language (also in some sense a predecessor of Go, especially the Goroutines.) And the Very Concurrent Garbage Collector that is used in Limbo, Inferno and also in some implementations of Standard ML. And UTF-8. So, it's not like  they haven't kept busy in the 40 years between Unix and Go.

Answer (score 3):

Not yet.

The authors of Go have very very deeply roots on non Windows operating systems ( Trivia: who of them created no less than the very UNIX operating system )

So, don't expect to have a Windows port from them any time soon.

The language is open source, so it will be just a matter of time ( make it from 6 - 8 ehrm months )  for a Windows implementation will be available.

Comment: Your connection between an author of Unix writing the compiler in his spare time and "don't expect a Windows port" is interesting, given that they point out in the changelog (see mbarnett's answer) that it's just because they do not have the resources.

Comment: Just another (soft) wording for "don't care".

Comment: Yes, is like Linus creating a port of git for Windows himself. That will never happen ( the port is being created by others though )

Answer (score 3):

So if you, like me, are on Windows a lot of the time and want to do some Go programming right now, you can do it on a VM. I use VirtualBox running Ubuntu in seemless mode. I already had it set up because I like Linux better than Windows for a lot of things.

Building and working with Go has been totally painless for me. I have a Bash open in a terminal to run my build and try my app. The source directory is a shared folder between Windows and Linux (a VirtualBox feature but I'm sure VMWare has the same thing). I edit my code in Komodo Edit on Windows and use Mercurial for the same source code on both OSes.

Comment: As suggested above I got ubuntu on the windows machine (with virtualbox) & then got go.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no Windows version at the moment, it can presumably be compiled using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) on a Windows platform.

Comment: You could compile it under cygwin w/ lots of rework, but even then, you would end up with a 6g/8g compiler that outputs ELF, not a native windows binary.  However, this would still be a good first step.

http://code.google.com/p/golang-on-cygwin/

Once builds are successful, the next step would be fixing the compiler to generate windows executable code.

Answer (score 0):

Various efforts to port Go to windows are underway.

The most advance and that can already build and run some code is here: http://code.google.com/r/hectorchu-go-windows/

Answer (score -2):

Installation of Go on windows is straight forward if you use the  [experimental x32 windows port](http://code.google.com/p/gomingw/downloads/detail?name=gowin386_release.r60.3_installer.exe&can=2&q=) . Documentation of the steps for [Go installation on windows](http://if-golang.blogspot.com/2011/11/installing-go-on-windows-7.html) can found [here](http://if-golang.blogspot.com/2011/11/installing-go-on-windows-7.html)

You will probably also want the MinGW tools (bash, make, gcc, etc...):
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/

and the GTK+ files and tools (the "all-in-one bundle" includes pkg-config):
http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php