# Can I use shared objects with Go?

Tags: shared-libraries, go

Can I use shared objects with Go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the Go [FAQ](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#Do_Go_programs_link_with_Cpp_programs), you can call into C libraries using a "foreign function interface":

> Do Go programs link with C/C++ programs?
>
> There are two Go compiler implementations, 6g and friends, generically called gc, and gccgo. Gc uses a different calling convention and linker and can therefore only be linked with C programs using the same convention. There is such a C compiler but no C++ compiler. Gccgo is a GCC front-end that can, with care, be linked with GCC-compiled C or C++ programs. However, because Go is garbage-collected it will be unwise to do so, at least naively.
>
> There is a “foreign function interface” to allow safe calling of C-written libraries from Go code. We expect to use SWIG to extend this capability to C++ libraries. There is no safe way to call Go code from C or C++ yet.

To answer your earlier question about Windows DLL's: no, as there is currently not a windows implementation of Go. For more information, read [can-go-compiler-be-installed-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717652/can-go-compiler-be-installed-on-windows)

Comment: I see that he tagged his question with "dll", but shared objects aren't exclusive to Windows, correct?

Comment: Actually, you can call Windows DLL functions and there is a partial Windows implementation of Go. It's just not well documented yet.

Comment: Cool... Do you have a link or any more info?

Comment: @Justin There was a recent mailing list thread about it: http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/6c3a256bacfffe0e