# How can I call linux shared library functions in Go?

Tags: go, shared-libraries

I have a .so file whose functions I would like to call in my Go code.

How do I go about doing that ? I have read the cgo and syscall package. They are close to what I want but I don't see any place where I can call the functions in the .so file.

I want to achieve exactly what the ctypes package does in Python.

Can somebody help ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can i use shared objects with Go (Google) programming language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254777/can-i-use-shared-objects-with-go-google-programming-language)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use a shared library that is known statically at compile time, you can simply use [cgo](http://golang.org/cmd/cgo). Read the documentation on how to do that exactly, but usually you specify some linker flags and a couple of commented out lines. Here is an example on how to call function `bar()` from `libfoo.so`.

```
package example

// #cgo LDFLAGS: -lfoo
//
// #include <foo.h>
import "C"

func main() {
    C.bar()
}
```

You can also use cgo to access shared objects that are being loaded dynamically at runtime. You can use `dlopen()`, `dlsym()`, and `dlclose()` to open a shared library, retrieve the address of one of the functions inside and finally close the library. Notice that you can't do these things in Go, you have to write some wrapper code in C that implements the neccessary logic for you.

Comment: I see that I have to specify the header function in the comment section and then call them. Let me see what I can do.

Comment: @AgnivaDeSarker I might have misunderstood your question a little bit. Let me rephrase my answer.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted ! I was just missing the LDFLAGS part.

Comment: @fuz, How does Go knows that the so file is `libfoo.so` if you don;t include it's name in Go source code that you provided?

Comment: @trojek The LDFLAGS directive does that.

Comment: @fuz, will your example works with C++ lib or only with C?

Comment: @trojek Please do not use comments under a question for extended discussion on other, unrelated questions.  Instead, do some research, ask elsewhere, or make a new question.

Comment: @trojek But for the record: CGo is meant to interact with C functions.  It thus needs a C declaration and a function that has C linkage (in C++, this is done with `extern "C"`).  Cgo does not understand C++ nor can it link to functions with C++ linkage.