# How to call my linux shared library function

Tags: linux, go, shared-libraries

I have a .so file whose functions I would like to call in my Go code.

I made the .so and test in other language and it's work, how can I call my function in Go?
Here is my code, I load library and when print the function result show only memory address.

```
package main

// #cgo LDFLAGS: -ldl
// #include <stdio.h>
// #include <dlfcn.h>
// #include <stdlib.h>
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {    
    var soName = C.CString("./myLibrary.so")    
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(soName))
    
    handle := C.dlopen(soName, C.RTLD_LAZY)
        
    var nmFuncao = C.CString("memoWrit")
    
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(nmFuncao))
    
    var fun1 = uintptr(C.dlsym(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(handle)), nmFuncao))

    var fun2 := C.dlsym(handle, nmFuncao)
    
    fmt.Println(handle)
    fmt.Println(fun1)
    fmt.Println(fun2)
}
```

The result is:

0x2585890
140436609898576
0x7fb9f23f1850

After load how can I call my "memoWrit" function?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149299/how-can-i-call-linux-shared-library-functions-in-go or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149299/how-can-i-call-linux-shared-library-functions-in-go help?

Answer (score 1):

I found how solve this, calling library procedure in C.

```
package main

// #cgo LDFLAGS: -ldl
// #include <stdio.h>
// #include <dlfcn.h>
// #include <stdlib.h>
//
// void memoWrit(void *lib) {
//  void (*func)(void) = NULL;
//  char *error = NULL;
//  func = (void (*)(void))(dlsym(lib, "memoWrit"));
//  error = dlerror();
//  if (func == NULL || error != NULL) {
//    fprintf(stderr, "Error no such function or procedure! (%s)\n", error);
//    return;
//  }
//  fprintf(stderr, "procedure 'memoWrit' loaded\n");
// (*func)();
//}
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    //The path and name of library file .SO
    var soName = C.CString("./myLibrary.so")
    //After execute, clear the memory
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(soName))
    
    //Open library
    handle := C.dlopen(soName, C.RTLD_LAZY)
    
    //Execute C procedure with no params
    C.memoWrit(handle)
}
```