# Issue with Installing Go in Windows

Tags: go

I download GO compiler for windows from http://code.google.com/p/gomingw/downloads/list. However, in Read Me file, it stated that for installation information, check http://golang.org/doc/install.html#install. But, in golang.org, there is only information about Linux installation, not for windows. Can anybody help me by specifying how to install it or giving a source where can I found the steps of installation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Go compiler be installed on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717652/can-go-compiler-be-installed-on-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the [`gowin386_release.r60.3_installer.exe`](http://code.google.com/p/gomingw/downloads/detail?name=gowin386_release.r60.3_installer.exe&can=2&q=) file and run it.

Comment: thanks a lot. However, can you help me about how to run it. What I am trying to follow is, go to src folder and give command 8g a.go (I have 64 bit compiler). Is it correct ? Actually, it gives error "open a.go nosuch file or directory".